# Explain data management of storyboards?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I have this UIImageView in one of my view controllers
[image]

I've set it as a subclass of this cutsom UIImageView, ABProfileImageView
[image]

Here's that ProfileImageView class:

```
#import "ABProfileImageView.h"


@implementation ABProfileImageView

-(id)init {
    self = [super initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"X4Hibreb.jpeg"]];
    if (self) {
        self.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"X4Hibreb.jpeg"];
    }
    return self;

}

@end
```

and I have an image name X4Hibreb.jpeg in the project folder,

[image]

So I'm not sure why the imageview doesn't have the picture I set it to be? I think it's some higher understanding thing that I don't get, I usually do programmatic UI's, this is the first time I'm using a storyboard.

Comment: If you're loading from a storyboard (or xib) try implementing initWithCoder instead of init.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have implemented `init`, however you also need to implement `initWithCoder:`, which is the initializer called when decoding objects from NIB files and storyboards.

Usually a good practice is to move common code from `init` and `initWithCoder:` to a `_commonInit` method and call it in the `init`.

Comment: What would I make the `NSCoder`?

Comment: @AndrewSB You wouldn't make it. The system makes it and calls your initializer with it. All you have to do is call `self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];`.

Comment: [IMAGE](http://i.imgur.com/B4YKUDk.png) this is what I have, still not sure why it isn't working properly

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the imageview.